# Get upper and lower date of ranges for birthday timeframe in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate two dates, the date a week before and the date eight weeks after a user´s birthday.

In our example we would like to grant the user access to some specials in a timeframe around his birthday.
1 week before his birthday
until
8 weeks after his birthday

```
e.g. #1

User birthday: 1988-01-05
Timeframe should be: YYYY-12-29 to YYYY-03-03

Current Date:  
1) 2016-12-30 
2) 2017-01-01 
3) 2017-02-01
4) 2016-12-28
5) 2017-12-28

Result should be:
1) True
2) True
3) True
4) False
5) False

e.g. #2
User birthday: 1988-12-30
Timeframe should be: YYYY-12-23 to YYYY-02-24

Current Date: 
1) 2016-12-30 
2) 2017-01-01 
3) 2017-02-01
4) 2016-12-28
5) 2017-12-28

Result should be:
1) True
2) True
3) True
4) True
5) True
```

Has anyone tried to accomplish something similar and can help me out here with some basic example, to light the bulb over my head?

Comment: Have you looked into [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) at all? It's a great library for dealing with dates.

Comment: The birthdays are statically in PHP or in a DB?

Comment: All user data comes from the DB and is represented by a user entity (birthdate is a DateTime field)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with the [carbon library.](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
$dt = Carbon::create(1991, 1, 31, 0); // Set the birthday
$dt->addWeeks(8); // Gives you a date 8 weeks after
$dt->subWeek(); // Gives you a date 1 week before
```

And then you don't have to deal with crazy date manipulation which is a huge pain.

Comment: Do you know if it is also possible to check if TODAY is in this timeframe, ignoring the year?

Comment: You could `Carbon::create(currentYear, birthMonth, birthDay)`, `Carbon::create(currentYear - 1, birthMonth, birthDay)`, `Carbon::create(currentYear + 1, birthMonth, birthDay)` and with each of those add 8 weeks and subtract 1. Then just check if the current date is within any of those 3 ranges.

Comment: True, that I guess that would work, will try that out (but I think I will stick to PHP DateTime, isn´t that much different). 
But the problem is that I also need the real Dates of the lower and upper border, and that drives me crazy to getting out the real year for those Dates.

Comment: I'm confused by the second part "But the problem is that I also need the real Dates of the lower and upper border, and that drives me crazy to getting out the real year for those Dates."

Comment: Sorry :D 
I want to show the date range to the user. So I would need the lower and upper range date.

Comment: Ok I just checked, which of the three ranges matched and took those dates.